# Custom seekbar with range

Tags: range, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

For one of my project I am working on a custom `seekbar`, I need a `seekbar` like this  [image] .

I am almost close to my destination with a great library [two thumb `seekbar`](https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar),I have followed the custom Drawable class which draws the ranged `seekbar` . In the library the value text has been drawn using paintText method . As I am not experienced in android,

I don´t know how to draw these two range value text like the requirement and a bubble image with them . Can anyone help me or give me some hints how to get this effect .

thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find [RangeSeekBar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) class from the link. You can customize the view further.